# Rails on save error and re-rendered page, show UNSAVED attributes & errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The classic Rails set up is something like this

```
def manage
  @o = Object.new
end

def create
  @o = Object.new(params)
  if @o.save
    redirect_to "something"
  else
    render "manage"
  end
end

# view for manage
<div id="errors">
  <%  if @o.errors.any? %>
    <ul>
      <% @o.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</div>

<input name="attribute" value="<%= @o.attribute %>">
```

The key benefit being that if attribute threw an error, the re-rendered page would show:

- the object's error
- the object's attribute that was NOT saved as the default value in the input field, so the user doesn't have to retype things

That's great! However, in my case, in my view file I have an additional line of code that looks like this:

```
<% if @o.attribute == 2 %>
  <div id="show-this"></div>
<% end %>
```

If the user tried to set `@o.attribute = 2` but that failed due to a validation error, I want the page to render with the error message displayed, but simultaneously because `@o.attribut != 2` in reality, I do NOT want to display the `#show-this` div. Obviously, I could remove the `#show-this` by a `redirect` or a `reload` on the entire object, but then that would no longer make the errors show...

I can think of different ways to do this, namely:

- in the custom validation, reset the `attribute` to nil myself if it doesn't save
- move the errors to a flash which can be used with a `redirect` that reloads the `@o`

BUT, I'm wondering if Rails already has a way of doing this... basically something that allows me to easily reload just one attribute, or check what the "post-save" value of that attribute should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code, you could just add

```
<% if @o.attribute == 2 and @o.errors.empty%>
  <div id="show-this"></div>
<% end %>
```

Semantics could be off, but this would be simple way to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but adding the `||=` to `manage` and calling `manage` in `create` might work:

```
def manage
  @o ||= Object.new
end

def create
  @o = Object.new(params)
  if @o.save
    redirect_to "something"
  else
    manage
  end
end
```